# How to merge/combine two Google Drive accounts?

Tags: google-drive, google-account

I have an old and a new Google account to work on Drive. On my old Drive I have a lot of shared folders from customers. Now I don't want to ask all my customers to invite my new account to their folders again.

Is there a way I can merge/combine my old account to my new account? I've read [this article](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-sync-your-multiple-Google-accounts-into-one-so-that-Google-Drive-can-handle-them-all), but I was hoping there would be a more easy way.

Comment: Hi Dees040, can you please mark an answer as accepted if your question has been thoroughly covered. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63304?hl=en) you can't merge two accounts. Check if your clients gave your account permission to share the files/folders. If they did then you can share them with your new account.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this. You will need to do the following with each file.

1. Share the file from your old account to your new account.
2. From your old account, make new account the Owner of each file.

This preserves the shares, but won't work for any file you don't own. Additionally if either of these are Google Apps accounts, your IT may have restrictions in place that prevent these actions.

File ownership can also be managed via Google APIs, which means there are 3rd party tools that can make this type or process easier. One such tool is [AODocs](https://goo.gl/XUFTj9).